# Problem with nested data using purrr: converted TS object has datatype character instead of dbl. Issue persist despite explicit coercion

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, purrr, nested-lists

I have nested table with 45 rows, and I would like to convert train data to time series objects *ts* and *msts* for fitting. So that has been done with no issue, however I notice that the params list contains character type S3:ts objects, which is out of the ordinary because the previous times I have done this the datatype is usually dbl. As a result I'm unable to fit the models, because of this non-numeric TS objects. I tried a workaround to use lapply for all elements inside the list to convert them to numeric, but when this is done its no longer a time series object.

```
#Nest the new tables
walmart_improve_nested <- walmart_data_improve %>%
  group_by(Store) %>%
  nest()

#Cross Validation
walmart_improve_nested <- walmart_improve_nested %>%
  mutate(train = map(data, train_split),
         test = map(data, test_split))

#Decompose and plot
walmart_ts_decompose <- function(df){
  df$Weekly_Sales = as.numeric(df$Weekly_Sales)
  ts(df$Weekly_Sales, frequency=52) %>% decompose() %>% autoplot()
}

walmart_msts_decompose <- function(df){
  df$Weekly_Sales = as.numeric(df$Weekly_Sales)
  msts(df$Weekly_Sales, seasonal.periods = c(4, 12, 26, 52)) %>% mstl() %>% autoplot()
}

#Visualize decomposed plots 
walmart_improve_nested <- walmart_improve_nested %>% 
  mutate(ts_decompose = map(train, walmart_ts_decompose),
         msts_decompose = map(train, walmart_msts_decompose))

#Create list of time series object functions
ts_function <- list(
  ts_obj = function(x) ts(as.numeric(x$Weekly_Sales), frequency=52),
  msts_obj = function(x) msts(as.numeric(x$Weekly_Sales), seasonal.periods = c(4,12,26,52))
)


#As there are two objects, replicate each unique Store number twice i.e one for each time series object
ts_function<- ts_function %>% 
  rep(length(unique(walmart$Store))) %>% 
  enframe("ts_func_name", "ts_func") %>% 
  mutate(Store = sort(rep(unique(walmart$Store), length(unique(.$ts_func_name)))))


#left join 
walmart_improve_nested <- left_join(walmart_improve_nested, ts_function) 

model_function <- list(
   stlm = function(x) stlm(x),
   tbats = function(x) tbats(x),
   HoltWinters = function(x) HoltWinters(x)
   )

model_function<- model_function %>% 
  rep(length(unique(walmart$Store))) %>% 
  enframe("model_name", "model_func") %>% 
  mutate(Store = sort(rep(unique(walmart$Store), length(unique(.$model_name)))))

#left join 
walmart_improve_nested <- left_join(walmart_improve_nested, model_function) 

walmart_improve_nested <- walmart_improve_nested %>%
  mutate(params = map(train, ~list(x = .x)))

walmart_improve_nested <- walmart_improve_nested %>% 
  mutate(
    data = invoke_map(ts_func, params),
    params = map(data, ~list(x = .x))
  )
```

The above code runs fine and are as expected with the exception of the class of the params list, which is character instead of dbl like usual. I have explicitly coerce the target variable as numeric but somehow the resulting TS object becomes character. I believe this is the cause of the problem as the other times when the type of params is 'dbl' there has been no issues.

Some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Please note that the following code results in error:

```
walmart_improve_nested <- walmart_improve_nested %>% 
  mutate(
    fitted = invoke_map(model_func, params)
  )
```

Error message:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `fitted = invoke_map(model_func, params)`.
ℹ In group 1: `Store = "1"`.
Caused by error in `map2()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `+.default`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
Backtrace:
  1. walmart_improve_nested %>% ...
 17. global `<fn>`(x = `<ts>`)
 18. forecast::stlm(x)
 19. forecast::mstl(x, s.window = s.window, robust = robust)
 21. base::NextMethod(.Generic)
```

I tried explicit coercion

I checked all my data and none of them are empty.

The step is successful until model fitting as it turns out they cannot work with the ts object converted (under params list)